# backgroundImage is null instead of Image

Tags: java, jpanel, draw

I'm relatively new to Java programming and here is some code where it should draw a background Image:

```
public class Board extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4759318639631503071L;
public String room = "menu";
public Image backgroundImage;

public Image getBackgroundImage() throws IOException{
    if (room == "menu") {
         backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/background_title.png"));
     }
    return backgroundImage;
}

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
 } 
}
```

I used System.out.println and realized that backgroundImage was null, what have I done wrong here?

Comment: The other question is, where is assets in relationship to the execution content?

Answer (score 0):

You have used `==` to compare strings

Use `if (room.equals("menu"))`

instead of

```
 if (room == "menu")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you should compare String objects using equals() method, since == operator checks whether two references point to exactly the same object.

So:

```
if(room.equals("menu")) { ... }
```

Comment: it still returns null, maybe there's something wrong with the paint method?

Comment: And where do you call this `getBackgroundImage()`? 
Do you call it at all and are you sure that it is called before `JPanel` calls this `paintComponent()`?